# How to get the cumulative sum of an aggregate column?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

I have this query in BigQuery that returns the representation of total `contributing_factor_vehicle_1`

```
SELECT
    TBL_TOTAL.contributing_factor_vehicle_1,
    TBL_TOTAL.TOTAL,
    (TBL_TOTAL.TOTAL / SUM(TBL_TOTAL.TOTAL) OVER ()) * 100  AS PERCENTAGE
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         contributing_factor_vehicle_1,
         COUNT(contributing_factor_vehicle_1) AS TOTAL
     FROM 
         `bigquery-public-data.new_york_mv_collisions.nypd_mv_collisions` 
     WHERE 
         borough = 'BROOKLYN' 
         AND contributing_factor_vehicle_1 <> 'Unspecified'
     GROUP BY 
         contributing_factor_vehicle_1
     ORDER BY 
         TOTAL DESC) TBL_TOTAL
ORDER BY 
    TOTAL DESC
```

Output:

| contributing_factor_vehicle_1 | TOTAL | PERCENTAGE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Driver Inattention/Distraction | 65427 | 28.913538237178777 |
| Failure to Yield Right-of-Way | 25831 | 11.415250679452903 |
| Backing Unsafely | 16384 | 7.240426895286917 |
| Following Too Closely | 12605 | 5.570408997503148 |
| Passing Too Closely | 10875 | 4.805886382217116 |

Now I need to get the cumulative `PERCENTAGE` to make a pareto analysis:
How do I achieve it please? Is it possible to use the column `PERCENTAGE` in a window function again?

| contributing_factor_vehicle_1 | TOTAL | PERCENTAGE | PERCENTAGE CUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Driver Inattention/Distraction | 65427 | 28.91% | 28.91% |
| Failure to Yield Right-of-Way | 25831 | 11.42% | 40.33% |
| Backing Unsafely | 16384 | 7.24% | 47.57% |
| Following Too Closely | 12605 | 5.57% | 53.14% |
| Passing Too Closely | 10875 | 4.81% | 57.95% |

Answer (score 4):

Just add one more line into the outer SELECT as in below example

```
SELECT
  TBL_TOTAL.contributing_factor_vehicle_1,
  TBL_TOTAL.TOTAL,
  ROUND((TBL_TOTAL.TOTAL/SUM(TBL_TOTAL.TOTAL) OVER ())* 100, 2)  AS PERCENTAGE,
  ROUND(((SUM(TBL_TOTAL.TOTAL) OVER (ORDER BY TOTAL DESC))/SUM(TBL_TOTAL.TOTAL) OVER ())* 100, 2) AS PERCENTAGE_CUM
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    contributing_factor_vehicle_1,
    COUNT(contributing_factor_vehicle_1) AS TOTAL
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_mv_collisions.nypd_mv_collisions` 
    WHERE borough = 'BROOKLYN' AND contributing_factor_vehicle_1 <> 'Unspecified'
    GROUP BY contributing_factor_vehicle_1
    ORDER BY TOTAL DESC 
) TBL_TOTAL

ORDER BY TOTAL DESC
```

with output

[image]